# Radicals' formation

Tags: valence-bond-theory, radicals

If carbon atom is tetravalent while oxygen atom is divalent so when they combine together the result should be $\ce{C2O4}$ then how are there compounds of formulas with $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{CO3}$  and others? How do they bond?

Comment: $\ce{CO2}$ is not a radical.

Comment: Yes sorry i got confused .. but i want to ask about their formation regarding valencies

Comment: Could you please tell me first what you would consider the definition of a radical?

Comment: Group of atoms that act like one atom during the chemical reaction .. ? I don't know much, i am asking so may someone correct my information about radicals

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is the lewis structure of $\ce{CO_2}$.Each bond symbolises of sharing of two electrons.One from oxygen and other from carbon.

[image]

You can imagine $\ce{CO_2}$ as such.

## **Your confusion**

[image]

[image]

Are you thinking something like this should be happening?[image]

Formation of $\ce{CO_2}$ can be calculted by transfer of valencies but cannot be explained.
And there are other compounds which cannot be calculated by valency transfer but can be explained  by Kossell-Lewis approach.

[image]

**Transfer of valencies only calculate and predict the formation of a compound.It does not explain.**

**$\ce{CO_2}$ is not a radical**

> In chemistry, a radical (more precisely, a free radical) is an atom, molecule, or ion that has unpaired valence electrons. Like this.
>   [image]